# Skobbler - ResourceNotFoundException for application label

Tags: android, skmaps

In a basic Skobbler application, when calling InitializeSKMaps, a ResourceNotFoundException is thrown with a reference to "string resource ID #0x0".  Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can occur because the Skobbler SDK (2.3) in InitializeSKMaps is expecting your manifest to have a label as shown below (along with corresponding strings.xml entry), and not a "fixed" string.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
```

It is doing something like:

```
int i = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
String str1 = context.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in 2.3 (and older versions) - the SDK uses the app_name string when reporting usage so that you get a better view in the analytics report. In 2.4 this will be handled more gracefully.

To fix this issue set in strings.xml this  key : `<string name="app_name">ApplicationName</string>`

Comment: I believe, in addition to this though, you need to have your manifest using something like:   
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
 </application>