# Initialize Skobbler 3.0.0 fails

Tags: android, skmaps

I am trying to upgrade from Skobbler 2.5.0 to 3.0.0 and Api fails to initialize. I have added the new Libs and new jni's also updated all changed API functions and followed the porting instructions.
I get following call stack:

```
 SKmaps----onMapTexturesPrepared - true<br>
 SKmaps---- INITIALIZE SK MAPS WITH SETTINGS <br>
SKmaps----versionFileName = version3_android_3_0.txt<br>
SKMapInitSettings---- Map style  SKMapViewStyle{resourceFolderPath='/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/daystyle/', styleFileName='daystyle.json', styleDetail=null, displayPixelDensity=null}<br>
SKUtils----Return calculated device type HIGH<br>
SKmaps----initializeLibraryWithSettings - SKAdvisorSettings is null! creating it!<br>
 SKmaps----initializeLibraryWithSettings - SKAdvisorSettings =  SKAdvisorSettings [advisorVoice=en, resourcePath=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages/, advisorConfigPath=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/Advisor/, language=LANGUAGE_EN, advisorType=AUDIO_FILES]<br>
 AdvisorConfigPath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages/en/advisor_configfiles/<br>
 AdvisorBundlePath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/Advisor/<br>
 VisualAdvicesDirPath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/Advisor/Visual/<br>
 LanguageCode : en
 SKmaps----Map style json file /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/daystyle/daystyle.json styleDetail = HIGH<br>
 SKmaps----Style detail = HIGH Road Cache 96468992 POI cache = 4194304  SHAPE CACHE 50331648<br>
 Resurse---- shaders:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/.Shaders/<br>
 Shadre Path = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps/.Shaders/<br>
 displayPixelDensity = 3<br>
 before NG_Initialize()<br>
 passed NG_Initialize()<br>
 Resurse---- commonResourcesPath:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/SKMaps//.Common/<br>
 SKmaps----found proxyUser: null, proxyPassword: null<br>
 SKmaps----UID = d04295345c1f74156e3de1717d392be;9a8f97be73b8cbc46e3568cc3d3b4081;14a779cb9b6e566289a94659e39f92e;83e2dd8385ad1e835a8cc656e4b1a1<br>
 No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0


at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1409)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1503)
 at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:383)
 at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.a(SourceFile:565)
 at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.onMapTexturesPrepared(SourceFile:1249)
 at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread$1.run(SourceFile:101)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

If any suggestions please share.

Comment: To confirm: you replaced the .so files, the .jar and the SkMaps.zip? Do you get this error also when performing a new install on a clean devices or only when "updating" a previously installed app?

Comment: Yes, I've replaced the .so, .jar and SkMaps.zip. It occurs on new install, and also on update.

Comment: Please pack your project and send it to dev@telenav.com for further investigation

Answer (score 0):

It was related to this questiond: [app_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611880/skobbler-resourcenotfoundexception-for-application-label)

Strange that the old SDK worked.